# 404 Page not found in Django, even though regular expression is correct

Tags: python, regex, django, url

I have the following URL in my Django project:

```
url(r'^result/edit/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.edit_result, name='edit_result')
```

Unfortunately, even when I manually input http://127.0.0.1:8000/result/edit/2/, it gives back a "page not found", and the view function is not called. The view function can be seen below:

```
def edit_result(request, pk):
    result = get_object_or_404(Result, pk=pk)
    group = Group.objects.filter(pk=pk)
    results = Result.objects.filter(group=group)
    context = {
        'pending_results': results,
        'groups': group
    }

    return render(request, 'resultregistration/editresult.html', context)
```

Strangely, it works perfectly fine with: http://127.0.0.1:8000/result/edit/1/
(so with 1), but not with 2, even though both objects with primary keys are present in the database.

Does anyone know why the view function is not called, even though the regular expression is (I assume) correct?

Thank you!

Comment: How can you be sure the function isn't called?  Your regex is correct and will call that function for `/result/edit/2/`, so the only opportunity for a 404 is your `get_object_or_404()` call.  Is your URL definitely not mistyped, and your database definitely has the object present in the database?

Comment: You are correct, it seems like it is actually called. I created the object in the django Admin panel and can see it there. But it seems like it is not passed to the view. Thank you!

Comment: What is the URL for the admin edit page for your faulty object?

Comment: The URL for the admin edit page is: 
http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/resultregistration/group/2/change/
Now, when I removed the 404, it is loading the page but shows no information about the Group (the group is the object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a `Group` with `pk=2`, but you do not have a `Result` with `pk=2`.

This means that your request to `/result/edit/2/` fails to retrieve a `Result`, then raises a 404.

One thing which seems weird to me now is that you're using the same PK to refer to different models.  Why not use a foreign key or one to one field?  Then you could simply:

```
result = get_object_or_404(Result, pk=pk)
group = result.group
...
```

Comment: You are completely right! Thank you so so much :D I truly appreciate it!

Comment: Sometimes you just need some more eyes.  If you need and help on relational database stuff, check out the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/).